# The drop-down list of events in VISUAL STUDIO did not appear

Tags: visual-studio, events, drop-down-menu, visual-studio-2015

In my visual studio the dropdown menu of events does not appear, I add an image to show what should go:
[image]

How I can enable this menu, appears to me again?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show it again by going to the Tools menu -> Option then in Text Editor -> (You language) -> General check the "Navigation Bar" checkbox:

[image]

Comment: Glad I could help :)